# JavaScript function with parameter runs once and can't be called again

Tags: javascript, html, function, button

A JavaScript function I made isn't finishing/starting at the second time properly, and as a result, I can only see the effects once.

```
            <button class="taken" id="A05" onclick="funcao('A05')">05</button>
            <button class="free" id="A04" onclick="funcao('A04')">04</button>
            <button class="taken" id="A03" onclick="funcao('A03')">03</button>
            <button class="free" id="A02" onclick="funcao('A02')">02</button>
            <button class="taken" id="A01" onclick="funcao('A01')">01</button>
```

I had this set of buttons in my html code, and each of them is tied to the function below, in a separate .js file.

```
function funcao(str){
    a = '#' + str;
    const botao = document.querySelector(a);

    const colecao = document.getElementsByClassName("free");
    for(let x = 0; x < colecao.length; x++){
        //alert(`Botao atual: ${colecao[x].id}`);
        if(colecao[x].id == botao.id){
            const aviso = document.querySelector('#default');
            aviso.id = 'warning';
            botao.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(255, 68, 0)";
            break;
        }
        else if(colecao[x].id < botao.id){
            const aviso = document.querySelector('#default');
            aviso.id = 'ativo';
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

It works perfectly the first time, and the result is one of the buttons change color if it was selected while having the "free" class. If not, the warning message, previously hidden in the background of the page, is lit in red.

However, when clicking in any button again, the effects of a second run aren't observed, and instead the buttons and/or the warning aren't changed by any means, most likely because the function doesn't run again.

The issue, I believe, is in the function parameter, but as I'm new to HTML and javaScript, i'm not so sure how to fix this.

Comment: After you do `aviso.id = 'ativo'`, it won't have the `default` ID any more, so the next time you call the function the query selector won't find anything. Changing IDs dynamically is usually a bad idea, you probably should use a class instead.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `event` of the click to tell which button was clicked.

```js
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");

buttons.forEach(function(button){
  button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    alert(event.target.id)
  });
});
```

```html
            <button class="taken" id="A05">05</button>
            <button class="free" id="A04">04</button>
            <button class="taken" id="A03">03</button>
            <button class="free" id="A02">02</button>
            <button class="taken" id="A01">01</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot one element with the `default` id, It's ok.

If you didn't have this element your code didn't execute even for the first time.

Anyway, we need an element with a `default` id.

### What is the problem?

Your code working for the first time because:

when for the first time you execute the code, one of the if statements run and will change 'default' to `warning` or `ativo`.

So next time there is no `default` id because you changed it and these codes are not working:

```js
 aviso.id = 'warning'; //aviso is null

 aviso.id = 'ativo';
```

And you will get this `TypeError`:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'id')
```

---

### What is the solution?

I think this code is better:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <p id="default">default</p>
    <button class="taken" id="A05">05</button>
    <button class="free" id="A04">04</button>
    <button class="taken" id="A03">03</button>
    <button class="free" id="A02">02</button>
    <button class="taken" id="A01">01</button>

    <script>
      const colecao = document.getElementsByClassName("free");
      const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");
      const aviso = document.getElementById("default");
      buttons.forEach((button) => {
        button.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
          const id = event.target.id;
          const botao = document.getElementById(id);
          for (let item in colecao) {
            if (colecao[item].id == botao.id) {
              aviso.id = "warning";
              botao.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(255, 68, 0)";
            } else if (colecao[item].id < botao.id) {
              aviso.id = "ativo";
              break;
            }
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

there are two changes :

1. I get an element with a `default` id outside of the function
2. I used `addEventListener` instead of `onclick`(not necessary but it's better thanks to @ronnie-royston)
3. And I used `for..in` instead of a simple `for` (this one is not necessary too)

**The first change will fix your code because You got an element with a `default` id before so there is no need for that element again**

Comment: Don't use a ternary when an `if` is appropriate. And while this will make the error go away, I don't think it will make the function work as intended.

Comment: yes but i should change code you can't check `aviso` in that `if`
i will fix it soon